# How to use encrypted subscriber_key from abandoned cart DE in journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, encryption, subscriber-key

Abandoned cart configuration has been setup in Marketing cloud.
Tracking code has been added in the website and all the necessary implementations are carried out on Marketing cloud end.
Behavioral triggers has been activated and data is flowing into the platform successfully (automatically generated Abandoned_Cart DE).
Now, Abandoned_Cart DE created from behavioral triggers is yet to be added as entry source in Journey. But, subscriber_key is in the SHA256 hashed format, how can we parse this and generate relevant email addresses in the data extensions for use in the journey settings.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The platform should know the email address and will deploy accordingly.

I *do* think you can parse the data out, but I'm not the one to ask.